# Bootstrap dropdown mega menu being triggered by the wrong events

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Problem summary

My dropdown is getting triggered by hovering elsewhere on the page.

Issue occurring is displayed here: https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFiX3kFzkv

---

### Details

1. After hovering over the mega menu "services" allow the mega menu to close by hovering off of it, then move the mouse back over a position on the webpage where the mega menu opened and it will open back up, even though the mouse did not hover over the "services" tab.
2. The mega menu dropdown "services" does not: stay open when clicked or redirect to the link when clicked. Can someone help me figure this out please, I'm not sure why it doesn't redirect there is a link to a separate page but it doesn't do anything.

---

### Code

#### Javascript

```
//Submenu Dropdown Toggle
if($('.main-header .main-menu li.dropdown ul').length){
    $('.main-header .main-menu li.dropdown').append('<div class="dropdown-btn"><span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></div>');

    //Dropdown Button
    $('.main-header .main-menu li.dropdown .dropdown-btn').on('click', function() {
        $(this).prev('ul').slideToggle(500);
    });

    //Megamenu Toggle
    $('.main-header .main-menu li.dropdown .dropdown-btn').on('click', function() {
        $(this).prev('.mega-menu').slideToggle(500);
    });

    //Disable dropdown parent link
    $('.main-header .main-menu .navigation li.dropdown > a,.hidden-bar .side-menu li.dropdown > a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}



//Tabs Box
if($('.tabs-box').length){
    $('.tabs-box .tab-buttons .tab-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $($(this).attr('data-tab'));

        if ($(target).is(':visible')){
            return false;
        }else{
            target.parents('.tabs-box').find('.tab-buttons').find('.tab-btn').removeClass('active-btn');
            $(this).addClass('active-btn');
            target.parents('.tabs-box').find('.tabs-content').find('.tab').fadeOut(0);
            target.parents('.tabs-box').find('.tabs-content').find('.tab').removeClass('active-tab');
            $(target).fadeIn(300);
            $(target).addClass('active-tab');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can't replicate it. Can you take a screencast and post a link.

Comment: @JGallardo Yes doing now

Comment: @JGallardo https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFiX3kFzkv

Comment: Can you post your javascript code that shows what triggers your dropdown. also what browser are you using?

Comment: @JGallardo Apologies for late response, the javascript should be from bootstrap 4 but I'll find out, and using Google Chrome.

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting down voted, if someone could please help me out I could pay for service.

Comment: I hope you don't take it personal, my vote was for the question, not you at all. I will remove my downvote since you updated with code. The question did not have enough detail and when posting here we expect there to be more specific technical questions with code that we can troubleshoot.

Comment: @JGallardo I'm new to this website, I don't understand why you did that, especially because I did everything you asked, I gave you the code I gave you a screencast, and you still never helped me.

Comment: My role here was editing for clarity, helping you to clarify your question, and making it more understandable for others who can answer. otherwise the questions like this lacking details just get closed.

Comment: @JGallardo Alright.